# Spring Boot Kotlin API returns 404 response for all endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm using Spring Boot with Kotlin . The rest controller returns 404 error for all endpoints. In the starting logs the endpoints in the controller are not present. Any endpoint returns the same 404 response.

These are the steps I have tried,

1. Tried clearing cache/target
2. Moved all classes into single directory
3. Tried adding ComponentScan annotation but it is not accepted.
4. I'm using cmd line to run the project
5. Same output seen when running java -jar $jarfile
6. Checked annotations Repository , Service , RestController

Controller:

```
package com.example.controller

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody

import Cricketer
import CricketerRepository
import CricketerService
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class CricketerController(private val cricketerService: CricketerService , private val cricketerRepository: CricketerRepository){

    @GetMapping("/cricketers/{id}")
    fun getCricketer(@PathVariable("id") id: Long):ResponseEntity<Cricketer>  {
        val cricketer = cricketerService.findById(id)
        return ResponseEntity<Cricketer>(cricketer as Cricketer, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/cricketers/")
    fun getAllCricketers() :ResponseEntity<List<Cricketer>>  {
        var cricketersList: ArrayList<Cricketer> =  cricketerService.getAllPlayers() as (ArrayList<Cricketer>)
        return ResponseEntity<List<Cricketer>>(cricketersList, HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    @PostMapping("/cricketer/")
    fun addCricketer(@RequestBody cricketer:Cricketer):ResponseEntity<Cricketer>  {
        val cCricketer : Cricketer = Cricketer(name = cricketer.name
                , country = cricketer.country
                , highestScore = cricketer.highestScore)
        cricketerRepository.save(cCricketer)
        return ResponseEntity<Cricketer>(cricketer , HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    @PutMapping("/cricketer/{id}")
    fun updateCricketer(@PathVariable("id") id: Long, @RequestBody cricketer: Cricketer ):ResponseEntity<Cricketer> {
        val cCricketer  = Cricketer(name = cricketer.name
                , country = cricketer.country
                , highestScore = cricketer.highestScore)
        cricketerRepository.save(cCricketer)
        return ResponseEntity<Cricketer>(cricketer, HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/cricketer/{id}")
    fun deleteCricketer(@PathVariable("id") id:Long ):ResponseEntity<String> {
        val cCricketer :Cricketer  = cricketerService.findById(id) as Cricketer
        cricketerRepository.delete(cCricketer)
        return ResponseEntity<String>("cricketer removed", HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Kotlin-Rest-API</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring-Kotlin-Rest-API</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Kotlin REST API Example</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.41</kotlin.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>       
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>

                    <compilerPlugins>

                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>          
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Startup logs

```
2018-05-21 22:31:19.490  INFO 3061 --- [           main] c.e.d.SpringKotlinRestApiApplicationKt   : Starting SpringKotlinRestApiApplicationKt on nirmal-desktop with PID 3061 (/home/nirmal/code/workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/Spring-Kotlin-Rest-API/target/classes started by root in /home/nirmal/code/workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/Spring-Kotlin-Rest-API)
2018-05-21 22:31:19.512  INFO 3061 --- [           main] c.e.d.SpringKotlinRestApiApplicationKt   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-21 22:31:19.592  INFO 3061 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5bab7c16: startup date [Mon May 21 22:31:19 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-21 22:31:29.492  INFO 3061 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$28d3b505] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-05-21 22:31:33.847  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-05-21 22:31:34.312  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-05-21 22:31:34.313  INFO 3061 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-05-21 22:31:34.389  INFO 3061 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-05-21 22:31:36.190  INFO 3061 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-05-21 22:31:36.190  INFO 3061 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 16602 ms
2018-05-21 22:31:36.560  INFO 3061 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-05-21 22:31:36.564  INFO 3061 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-21 22:31:36.566  INFO 3061 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-21 22:31:36.566  INFO 3061 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-21 22:31:36.566  INFO 3061 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-21 22:31:37.743  INFO 3061 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-05-21 22:31:39.038  INFO 3061 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-05-21 22:31:39.222  INFO 3061 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-21 22:31:39.480  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-05-21 22:31:40.064  INFO 3061 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-05-21 22:31:40.066  INFO 3061 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-05-21 22:31:40.302  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-05-21 22:31:42.180  INFO 3061 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2018-05-21 22:31:44.235  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@7d95eb4a'
2018-05-21 22:31:44.237  INFO 3061 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-21 22:31:44.688  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-21 22:31:46.829  INFO 3061 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5bab7c16: startup date [Mon May 21 22:31:19 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-21 22:31:46.894  WARN 3061 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-05-21 22:31:47.072  INFO 3061 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-05-21 22:31:47.073  INFO 3061 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-05-21 22:31:47.121  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-21 22:31:47.122  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-21 22:31:49.030  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-05-21 22:31:49.033  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-05-21 22:31:49.047  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-05-21 22:31:50.682  INFO 3061 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-05-21 22:31:50.695  INFO 3061 --- [           main] c.e.d.SpringKotlinRestApiApplicationKt   : Started SpringKotlinRestApiApplicationKt in 34.697 seconds (JVM running for 49.043)
```

Comment: What is the package of the main class?  It seems the controller class is not in one subpackage if this main class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess your `CricketerController` is not in a subpackage relative to your main class. So you basically have two options:

1. Place your main class directly under the package **com.example**
2. Add the annotation at the bottom of this answer to your main class.

Using any of these two methods makes the controller class visible for Spring at startup and therefore should create your mappings.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.controller"} )
```

Comment: I followed the proper directory structure relative to the main class but when I had refactored from the IDE, the package names were not updated properly

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = [ "com.example.controller" ])`